# Subsets in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1 \subset (\mathbb{Z}_3)^4$ generated by $(2,1,2,0),(2,0,2,1)$ and $(0,2,0,1)$ and $U_2 \subset (\mathbb{Z}_3)^4$ of equations:

$x + y + 2z + 2t = 0$
$x + y      + t  = 0$

How can I calculate $dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$?

I have tried  to calculate the equations of $U_1$ but I have $0 = 0$

Comment: "I have tried to calculate the equations of  $U_1$ but I have $0=0$". Can you show your work?

Comment: I have calculated the $det[(2,1,2,0), (2,0,2,1), (0,2,0,1), (x, y, z, t)]$ and it is 0=0, so I can't calculate the equations of $U_1$, and I can't do my exercise.

Comment: Your determinant is necessarily zero because your first three rows are already linearly dependent, as I pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start to a solution.

Your vectors  in $U_1$ are $a=(-1,1,-1,0)$, $b=(-1,0,-1,1)$ and $c=(0,-1,0,1)$. By doing row reduction on the associated matrix, I saw that $c=b-a$. So a basis for $u_1$ is $\{a,b\}$. Now let’s look at $a$ and $b$. Just by inspection, I saw that in both vectors, $x-z=0$ and $x+y+t=0$.

That gives you your two equations for $U_1$.

It seems to me that the intersection of the two spaces has dimension $1$.

Comment: I got that the dimension of the intersection is $0$.  Would you mind having a look at my answer to see if I made any incorrect assumptions about the problem?  I need to know whether or not to delete my answer.

Comment: Yes, your mistake is to say “$3z=0\Rightarrow z=0$”, it’s just a slip that I’m sure you can remedy quickly.

Comment: Good catch!  Thanks.

Comment: I tried fixing it, but it just got messier.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: How you have that $x-z = 0$ and $x+y+t = 0$ ? I don't understand this step

Comment: $x-z=0$ because in your two basis vectors, the first and third coordinate are equal. $x+y+t=0$ because this also is true for the two basis vectors. It was just eyeball work, though there are more systematic ways of doing it.

Comment: Ok, all right. I have done the process. Thank you